# How do I tell if initial geth sync is done in 'light' mode on testnet

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, testnets, light-clients

I just installed geth on Windows 10. Then I did the initial sync in light mode on testnet, and my status is as shown on the screenshot below.

[image]

I have two questions (related):

1. How do I tell if the sync is done?
2. If it is done, can I now close this command window before I start my experiments, say a "Hello, World" smart contract.

**Update**:

I tried `geth attach` as suggested by abattia, and got this error:

[image]

Comment: Try __geth attach ipc:\\.\pipe\geth.ipc__

Comment: it works now, thanks! do you mind updating the same in your answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Done. Glad that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I tell if the sync is done?

For Windows 10, from another terminal enter: `geth attach ipc:\\.\pipe\geth.ipc`.
Assuming the geth console opens OK, then enter `eth.syncing`. If you get the response `false`, then the node thinks it is synced. Otherwise, the command will return information about the status of the syncing (currentBlock, highestBlock, knownStates, pulledStates, startingBlock).

> If it is done, can I now close this command window before I start my
>   experiments, say a "Hello, World" smart contract.

Best to leave that terminal open, and do the rest of your tests from another terminal.

Comment: If the terminal has to be left open, does that mean if I shut down my computer, I will need to run through the syncing process again?

Comment: _If the terminal has to be left open, does that mean if I shut down my computer, I will need to run through the syncing process again?_  If you shut down your computer, the node will no longer be able to stay synced. If you then re-start your node, it doesn't need to re-start syncing completely; it picks up from where it got to, but will need to spend time syncing with the blocks created since it was shut off.

Comment: tried *geth attach*, doesn't seem to work, see my update on the question.